# Cookie jquery hide and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I wanna use my javascript cookie to let the application see if the user already loggedIn.. i get the value of the cookie in my console.. but whenever i make an statement and wanna hide a div the div doesn't do anything it doesn't show or hide.. can you guys please help me??

```
function writeCookie(name,value,days) {
   var date, expires;
   if (days) {
       date = new Date();
       date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
       expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
           }else{
       expires = "";
   }
   document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";

}
function readCookie(name) {
   var i, c, ca, nameEQ = name + "=";
   ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
       c = ca[i];
       while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
           c = c.substring(1,c.length);
       }
       if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
           return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
       }
   }
   return '';
} 

var user = readCookie('email');

if (!user) {
    document.getElementById('loginNav').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('username').style.display = 'block';
    $("#loginNav").css("display","block");
}else{
    $("#loginNav").css("display","block");
   console.log( $("#loginNav").css("display","block"));

}
```

Comment: Why are you using both plain JS and jQuery that does the same thing, and when is it supposed to hide, all I see is `display: block`, in both parts of the condition ?

Comment: @adeneo because none of the script I use doesn't work and i have the div on display none in my html but it doesn't show in both of the statement..

Comment: make sure you are executing the code after the page is loaded.

Comment: what's the value of "user" when you log it?

Comment: Soorry that my reaction is late because i felt sick.. My user value has something in it if i console.log(user) I get my email address but my function doesn't do anything.. :( @LShetty

Comment: @Dennis Hope you are feeling okay now. Could you create a fiddle with only the relevant code?

Comment: @LShetty yea i feel better now and the problem is solverd ;) thank you very much for you help

Answer (score 0):

if `$('#loginNav').length == 0` then your element has not been loaded yet.

Ensure that this code comes after your jquery link and it is surrounded by a :

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
var user = readCookie('email');
  if (!user) {
        $('#loginNav, #username').show();
    }else{
        $("#loginNav, #username").hide();    
        //did you forget to hide the username?
    }
});
```

Make sure you load all your JS files at the end of your HTML age.

Comment: Thank you for your help but if I try this it doesnt show or hide my email or my loginNav.. :$

Comment: if I console.log(user) than i get in my console.. =test123@live.nl @Grimbode

Comment: I think there is more to your problem then the code you are showing. Did a little test http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/osaj0c3L/ works fine.

Comment: I know but I don't know what the problem exactly is because i can't style anything of my html

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle? Or could you update your question with your html and css?

Comment: i don't know if this is where you asked for but I added my html block to the code.. http://jsfiddle.net/osaj0c3L/5/ @Grimbode

Comment: Honestly having trouble imagining what the problem could be. Everything you've added is working. Your code is fine. The only thing I can think that could be the issue: Do you have any errors in your console? Are you loading your JS after your JQUERY? Do you have any special CSS ?

Comment: Add this in your JS after "var user = readCookie('email');" : "alert($('#loginNav').length);" And tell me the value that is shown.

Comment: Hmm.. it says "0" @Grimbode

Comment: Then that is the beginning of your problem. It should say '1'. This means your element doesn't exist (at that specific moment).

Comment: Yea that's strange, because i make a button and add the same values and if i click on it it works.. @Grimbode

Comment: Are you sure you're using $(document).ready(function(){}); ? This alone should solve that problem. It forces the JS to wait till the document is ready.. meaning that al the elements exist.

Comment: Thank you very much @Grimbode !! when you said that the value was "0" from the div it's because the <head> is loaded but not yet the HTML i guess.. so i placed the script under my html and it's kinda logic but very thanks you helped me a lot! :D

Comment: Yes placing all your JS at the end of the docuent is a recommended practice. Good luck, glad I could help. And feel free to mark this as the correct answer. ;)

Comment: Haha but i still strange because you say document.ready but yea it works now thanks and I will mark it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi set the "display" property to "none" to hide.... and "block" to show
I would also use "visibility":

```
if (!user) {
    $("#loginNav, #username").css("display","block");
    $("#username, #username").css("visibility","visible");
}else{
    $("#loginNav, #username").css("display","none");
    $("#username, #username").css("visibility","hidden");
}
```